# animation in android, new to android

Tags: android, alpha

I have these 2 pictures:
[image]

[image]

and I´m trying to make an animation of them. I want to show the first picture (the one without wheels) and then the one with booth wheels. It shall be looking like the wheels have appeared, because the position will not be changed and the car shall not disappear. So I tried to use fade-in effect, because if I just "reload" my xml layout, it doesnt look very good.

I found many tutorials, but none of them did solve my problem. My question is: Does anybody know, how to do that?

Comment: Could you post the code you tried as well please and also define "it doesnt look very good" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use FrameLayout to stack two ImageView always show your first picture the one without weels and use any action listener to triger the animation on second ImageView using AlphaAnimation..

```
 Animation animation = new  AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
 animation.setDuration(1000); // anim duration in milli second
 animation.setRepeatCount(0); // 0 no repeat
 animation.setFillAfter(true); 
 iv.startAnimation(animation); // iv is your imageview
```